# In Angular, can I implement both Validator and AsyncValidator at the same time?

Tags: angular

I got multiple form controls in a form group (i.e. myForm below), which is a nested form of another form group.
Some of the form controls of this nested form use validators while some others use async validators.
So my class implements both Validator and AsyncValidator like the shown code snippets.

```
@Component({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComponent ),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComponent ),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComponent ),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor, Validator, AsyncValidator {
        public myForm: FormGroup;
    .......
    .......
    .......
        validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        return this.myForm.invalid ? { invalidForm: { valid: false, message: 'Form fields are invalid' } } : null;}
    
        validate(c: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
        return this.myForm.invalid ? { invalidForm: { valid: false, message: 'Form fields are invalid' } } : null;}
    
    }
```

However, it shows following errors:

> Duplicate function implementation.ts(2393) Property 'validate' in type
> 'MyComponent' is not assignable to the same property in base type
> 'AsyncValidator'.   Type '(c: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors' is
> not assignable to type '(control: AbstractControl) =>
> Promise | Observable'.ts(2416)

How should I fix it? I goolged for some blogs talking about validator/ async validator, but all of them only use either one of them but not both.

Thank you.

Comment: Ignoring the validation, that's not valid Typescript. So no you can't do that.

Comment: I think your class should just implement the AsyncValidator because it is already an extension of the Validator interface. Check out the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator).

Comment: @Liam, can you explain more why that's not valid Typescript? Thanks.

Comment: @riorudo, thanks for your reply. Following your suggestion, I've now just made changes (1) provide: [NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS],, (2) implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor, AsyncValidator (3) just add a console.log() inside validate(c: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {}. But the log never comes up. It seems like the validate() never being executed?

Comment: Because it's not. You have two method with the same signature. Typescript doesn't support this syntax. That's why you get a *Duplicate function*. TBH no language (that I'm aware of) would allow you to create two methods with the same signature with different return types. How would the processor know which method to use when?

Comment: @Liam, understood. I have just made changes as in previous comment. Do you have any idea to resolve that? Thanks again.